# Processing sketch crashing website

Tags: java, google-chrome, crash, processing, freeze

Made a new sketch on openprocessing.org to test for some different grade combinations quickly... but whenever I run it, the page freezes hangs until chrome says that it is unresponsive. My other sketches are working just fine, it is only this one.

Here is the sketch:

```
double a, o, u, k;
int[][] combos;
int[][] a_combos, b_combos;
int failcounter;

void setup() {
    size(100,100);
    background(100);
    noLoop();
    a = 2 + 4;
    o = 4 + 4;
    u = 3 + 4;
    k = 3 + 5;

    combos = new int[10000][4];
    a_combos = new int[10000][4];
    b_combos = new int[10000][4];
    failcounter = 0;
}

void draw() {
    fillCombos();
    for (int i = 0; i < combos.length; i++) {
        double atemp = a + combos[0];
        double otemp = o + combos[1];
        double utemp = u + combos[2];
        double ktemp = k + combos[3];
        double avg = (atemp + otemp + utemp + ktemp) / 4;

        if (avg >= 17) {
            a_combos[i] = combos[i];
        } else if (avg >= 13.48) {
            b_combos[i] = combos[i];
        } else {
            failcounter++;
        }
    }

    println("Getting an A:");
    for (int i = 0; i < a_combos.length; i++) {
        if (a_combos[i] != null) println(a_combos[i]);
    }
    println("Getting a B:");
    for (int i = 0; i < b_combos.length; i++) {
        if (b_combos[i] != null) println(b_combos[i]);
    }
    println("A or B versus C, D, or F:");
    println(10000 - failcount + ", " + failcount);
}

void fillCombos() {
    int q = 0;
    int w = 0;
    int e = 0;
    int r = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < combos.length; i++) {
        combos[i][0] = q;
        combos[i][1] = w;
        combos[i][2] = e;
        combos[i][3] = r;

        r++;
        if (r == 10) {
            r = 0;
            e++;
        }
        if (e == 10) {
            e = 0;
            w++;
        }
        if (w == 10) {
            w = 0;
            q++;
        }
    }
}
```

If I put print lines into several different locations in the code, none of them run for whatever reason. Any insight?

Comment: `double atemp = a + combos[0]` is trying to add a double with an integer array. You seem to be mentally switching back and forth between 1 and 2 dimensional arrays. You declared `combos` to be 2-dimensional, so `combos[0]` is itself an integer array. Similar remarks hold for your other arrays.

Comment: Have you tried [debugging your code](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/debugging) to figure out which line of code behaves differently from what you expected? Check the [JavaScript console](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/javascript/developer-tools) for errors as well.

Comment: @JohnColeman Thanks for the catch; as the website crashes whenever I attempt to open the sketch, I can't access the code and this was a quick five-minute remake of a previous version. However, those errors are not causing the website to crash, which is the main issue here. Possibly it is an issue with my computer? Can someone checl out (the initial version, may have syntax issues) at https://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/555960

Comment: Why not debug the sketch in the Processing IDE and then run it in Open Processing afterwards?

Comment: I can't view your sketch's code either. Maybe there is a bug in your sketch that is interacting with a bug in the error handling in Open Processing. If you look at the page source you might be able to find a url to the code itself. I did a quick look, but nothing jumped out.